# NSDate formatting using locale

Tags: objective-c, localization, timezone, nsdate

I was using the following method for creating NSDate Object based on the timezone and locale.

```
   descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:


[[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%Y-%m-%d"
                                    timezone:nil
                                      locale:nil];
```

But this method is no more found in the documentation.
   Any alternative methods that i can use ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you need to do it in 3 steps:

```
[date setFormat:@"YYYY-mm-dd"];
[date setTimeZone:tz];
[date setLocale:l];
```